# Difference between using Cloud Endpoints vs using authenticated requests for data?

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-endpoints, app-engine-ndb

I would like to make authenticated requests to a an App Engine app. I am having trouble setting up Cloud Endpoints(I have failed to follow the tutorial many times.) so I am thinking about an alternative to retrieve user data from the datastore. Can I just return a json object after a user makes a request to a specific URL?

**For example:**
I have a webapp called *Library of Books*. It's an awesome app that simply allows authenticated users to keep track of a list of their favourite books. This is the Book Entity:

The user can access his list of fav books by visiting `/my-fav-books`. When visiting this url, the user **sends his cookies which would validate his authenticated session** and the server could then return the user's list of books via a json object.

Could this work?

Comment: If you would like help on setting up Endpoints, you should detail the problems you're having. This can help us improve our documentation as well.

Comment: Hello @saiyr. I had submitted the issues at the time when I had encountered the problems.

Comment: It would be helpful to restate them here, if you have the time.

Comment: @saiyr, I am occupied now but I will create a separate post when I attempt again Cloud Endpoints again.